# How to link to python file inside html code

Tags: python, html, web, pyscript

So I have created a game (of sorts) in python that I want to embed into an html webpage so I can add UI features. I have used the  tags to do this but I am having issues with importing packages and also it clutters up the code. So is there a way to link to the python file instead, like I would a JS or CSS file?

I apologise in advance for any ambiguity or poor phrasing in my question, I am new to programming and don't really have anyone to turn to when I need help so I have to use SO for even the most minor errors.

Comment: Question is tagged "pyscript", do you confirm you have created it with the pyscript framework? If not, have you searched about it? The tag description mentions it's "for running python in the browser".

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that I am using the pyscript framework. I came across it in a previous SO question, the name of which escapes me.

Comment: Yes, I'm not having any errors, I was just wondering if I could have the python code in a separate file and then link to it inside the HTML file instead of having all the code in the HTML file

Comment: Yes, I understand the question better now. I was wondering if having a js script that adds dynamically all your the <py-script> tags would work. Seems it's the case : https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/executing-dynamically-created-pyscript/21327/5

Comment: That's maybe not the most elegant (would still be python code as text in a javascript file), but at least it would help to separate the python code from the rest of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, had a look at the link you sent and it looks like it would work, but it still doesn't really reduce the length of the html file which is what I was looking for. It seems like there are no simple solutions so I may just go with Django. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The pyscript docs do say they support [`<py-script>`](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/elements/py-script.html) and that it supports the `src` attribute. So, wouldn't it be `<py-script src="something.py"></py-script>`?

Comment: The javascript file injecting pyscript is _do_ reduce the length of the html file entirely, why doesn't it? Anywaay, last ocmment from Ouroborus should be the exact answer to your question. Regarding Django, it's radically different. It's not some python code executed in the browser, it's server side rendering (if I'm not mistaken). That may or may not be an alternative for your problem, it's unclear at that point. For a game, that would be surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re using a `<py-script>` tag, you can use the `src` attribute to reference a URL where the relevant python code is located. In this case, any code written within the tag itself (that is, in the HTML page) is ignored. For example:

```http
<py-script src="some/url/with/code.py"></py-script>
```

Note that the attribute is a URL, not a local file path, so you’ll likely want to use a small server program to make the python file available on the network. Running `python -m http.server` from the command line will do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really helpful. I'm trying to implement it but encountering and issue: when i initialise a local server to run it in and try to open the page in google it gives this site can't be reached error. I'm using this website: https://blog.logrocket.com/pyscript-run-python-browser/ as a guide. It's down in the External Pyscript section. Just a bit of context - I ran that command from the terminal from the folder my HTML and python files are stored in so hope that it OK. Also I'm confused about what sort of path is should put for the src, could you explain more about that?

Comment: When you run that command, what appears in the terminal? And out of curiosity, what shall terminal are you using? Sometimes I have found it necessary to specify the actual IP/port that the server should appear on, since it sometimes binds to something unintuitive by default like a local IPv6 address or or something.

Comment: This appears in the terminal: Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ... I have tried both the terminal in VS Code (my editor of choice) and the acutal windows cmd prompt. Would you mind explaining about the src path though? Currently I just have it listed as "/simulation.py" (as my python file is in the same folder as my HTML file.

Comment: Ah, so it looks like your command is binding to a local ipv6 interface. Try `python -m http.server -b 127.0.0.1`. You probably want to use just “simulation.py” as the src - that would be a relative URL that points to a file at the same path as the currently loaded file - if you start with a dash, you’re referring to a file at the root of the authoritative part of the url, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat. I think all the python is loading fine but i am getting an error with modules - I use several in my code such as pygame, matplotlib etc. When I run the python file on its own it works fine, but not when I run the HTML file even though I have <py-env> tags in which I declare? the modules I have to install. Any ideas? If you don't want to reply, don't worry, you've already fixed so much and I'm very grateful

Comment: Update: worked out that the <py-env> tags have been deprecated. <py-config> tags are being used instead. Still getting an error when the packages are imported but we're getting closer. (Error is a pure python 3 wheel can't be found)

Comment: The gist is - due to technical limitation, not all packages can be used in PyScript/Pyodide. [Only Pure Python packages or those specifically built with Pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#why-can-t-micropip-find-a-pure-python-wheel-for-a-package) can be used. But matplotlib should work… though pagans doesn’t currently. 

That said, are you using PyScript Alpha? Py-env was renamed py-config in version 2022.11.1. (Update - you beat me to it!)

Comment: I think I'm using the latest pyscript version - the link to the js file in head looks like this: https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js and the css file looks similar. Not sure how to check if I am using the alpha version. In terms of packages, I'm not  just using matplotlib and pygame unfortunately. I also use numpy, itertools and keyboard (although that last one isn't necessary).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251635/discussion-between-atomprogrammer-and-jeff-glass).